# Change current code from copying entire row to static range

Tags: excel, vba

Looking to adjust the code below from copying an entire row to a static range of rows (ie: A:Q)

```
Sub CopyRows()
Dim bottomL As Integer
Dim x As Integer
bottomL = Sheets("Pacer").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row: x = 1               

Dim c As Range
For Each c In Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:L" & bottomL)
    If (c.Value = "Group1" Or c.Value = "Group2" Or c.Value = "Group3") Then
        c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Formatted Data").Range("A" & x + 1)
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: What's your question/issue? You're pasting to `A` ...you want to iterate through `A`  to `Q` each time?

Comment: Right now the code works great to iterate through a messy report and copy over only rows in one of the 3 groups listed.  However, I would like to adjust it to only copy a given number of columns such that when I run the macro, any formulas I generate outside of the copy range will not be written over.  Hopefully that explanation makes a bit of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be easiest to use Intersect.

```
intersect(c.parent.columns("A:Q"), c.EntireRow).Copy Worksheets("Formatted Data").Range("A" & x + 1)
```

Comment: Success!  Thanks very much Jeeped, I wasn't aware of the Intersect function.  Just tested it and some text I placed outside of the copy/paste range remained intact.